# Transmitting command's input and output through Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh

Is it possible to transmit both input and output of a system command in the CLI - a command which would be executed through/by node.js?

I'm interested if it's possible to run something like:

```
ssh root@localhost
```

And get all the inputs and outputs provided by `ssh`, including everything after a successful login.

I've read on the matter and I've came up with this so far:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var ssh = spawn('ssh', ['root@localhost'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
var me = {};

ssh.stdout.on('data', console.log);
```

But it doesn't handle my inputs quite well.

Another question which I have here - is it possible to transmit (over network) all the inputs / outputs to clients and alike and allow user to interact with the command from the remote side?

Comment: Why doesn't it handle your inputs quite well? Do note that `ssh.stdout` is a stream, and you may have to retrieve multiple chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at a library such as [simple-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh). It should make your life simpler.